# Lines lying in a projective algebraic set

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, surfaces, projective-geometry, quadrics

I want to find all lines lying entirely in the projective algebraic set $XY-ZW=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$, where $X, Y, Z, W$ are homogeneous coordinates.

How can I do this?

Comment: A line in $\mathbb P^3$ is the complete intersection of two planes. A general line in $\mathbb P^3$ meets a quadric surface (your variety) in two points. So one way to proceed might be to understand, given two planes $F,G=0$ in $\mathbb P^3$, how to describe the line in which they intersect (perhaps parametrically), and then determine when such a line vanishes on the quadric (if you have a parametric description of the line, this should be easy).

Comment: So would perhaps one approach be to start with defining F as going through points lying on the line, say $(a_0: \cdots :a_3),(b_0: \cdots :b_3),(c_0: \cdots :c_3)$, then parametrising it by $(a_0X + b_0Y + c_0Z: \cdots: a_3X + b_3Y + c_3Z)$, and similarly for G with $(a_0Y + b_0 Z + c_0W: \cdots :a_3Y + b_3Z + c_0W)$?

Comment: A line on the surface lies in the tangent space to its point. So, intersect your surface with its tangent space.

Comment: @Sasha I've not done anything about tangent spaces yet